# SQL Server 2005 For XML Explicit - Need help formatting

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, formatting, for-xml

I have a table with a structure like the following:

---

| LocationID | AccountNumber |
| --- | --- |
| long-guid-here | 12345 |
| long-guid-here | 54321 |

To pass into another stored procedure, I need the XML to look like this:

```
<root> 
    <clientID>12345</clientID>
    <clientID>54321</clientID>
</root>
```

The best I've been able to do so far was getting it like this:

```
<root clientID="10705"/>
```

I'm using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    1 as tag,
    null as parent,
    AccountNumber as 'root!1!clientID'
FROM
    Location.LocationMDAccount
WHERE
    locationid = 'long-guid-here'
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

So far, I've looked at the documentation on [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137.aspx), but I've not come out with the desired results.

---

@KG,

Yours gave me this output actually:

```
<root>
  <Location.LocationMDAccount>
    <clientId>10705</clientId>
  </Location.LocationMDAccount>
</root>
```

I'm going to stick with the `FOR XML EXPLICIT` from Chris Leon for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    0 AS Parent,
    AccountNumber AS [Root!1!AccountNumber!element]
FROM
    Location.LocationMDAccount
WHERE
    LocationID = 'long-guid-here'
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Chris:

```
SELECT
    AccountNumber as [clientId]
FROM
    Location.Location root
WHERE
    LocationId = 'long-guid-here'
FOR
    XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

TERRIBLY SORRY! I mixed up what you were asking for. I prefer the XML AUTO just for ease of maintainance, but I believe either one is effective. My apologies for the oversight ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I got it with:

```
select
1 as tag,
null as parent,
AccountNumber as 'root!1!clientID!element'
from
Location.LocationMDAccount
where
locationid = 'long-guid-here'
for xml explicit
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server 2005 (or presumably 2008) I find for XML PATH to allow for much easier to maintain SQL than for XML Explicit (particularly once the SQL is longer).

In this case:

```
SELECT AccountNumber as "clientID"
FROM Location.LocationMDAccount
WHERE locationid = 'long-guid-here'
FOR XML PATH (''), Root ('root');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1             as tag,
       null          as parent,
       AccountNumber as 'clientID!1!!element'
FROM Location.LocationMDAccount
WHERE locationid = 'long-guid-here'
FOR XML EXPLICIT, root('root')
```